# Gradients are None in PyTorch for RL

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am new to PyTorch, and Reinforcement Learning, so I am practicing with the gym library, but I cannot get my model to train. I have narrowed it down to my grads being None, but I cannot figure out why. I suspect that it has something to do with the way I calculate reward/loss, but I cannot understand the problem.
I read that it might be because my parameters are detached from the computational graph, and I have tried everything to prevent that without any luck. I don't think I fully understand the computational graph... Code:

```
for episode in range(n_episodes):
        done = False
        obs, reward, done, info = env.reset()
        rewards = torch.tensor(0, dtype = torch.float32 ,requires_grad = True)
        
        while not done:
            
            observation = torch.from_numpy(obs)
            observation.requires_grad = True
            y_pred = model(observation)

            obs, reward, done, info = env.step(int(y_pred.clone().detach().numpy()[0]))
            
            rewards.cat(torch.tensor(-reward, requires_grad = True))
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = rewards.sum() 
        loss.retain_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

My model looks like this:

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_dim, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, output_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Softmax(dim= 0))
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)
```

I printed `list(model.parameters())[0].grad is None`, to find that it is always `True`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The fact that you are detaching the prediction to compute the reward means there is no gradient propagating from the loss to the model's parameters. Any particular reason why you are using `y_pred.clone().detach().numpy()[0])`?

Comment: I read somewhere that parameters could get detached when converted to numpy arrays like this.  But since i clone the tensor, I suppose it wouldn't make a difference...

Comment: Either way, this will prevent the gradient from flowing through, i.e. your parameters won't get updated. Do you have the definition for `env.step`? If this function is implemented with differentiable operators (in PyTorch's sense) then you will be able to keep the prediction on the graph...

Comment: Its is surprisingly hard to find out what that method accepts, but I found this 'Args: action (object): an action provided by the agent'. When trying for myself, it seems like it accepts ints. So I suppose I need a way to convert to an int without detaching the parameter.

Comment: Do you have a reference, link, or the actual source code for the loss function?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/openai/gym/tree/58aeddb62fb9d46d2d2481d1f7b0a380d8c454b1

Comment: Have you tried passing a PyTorch tensor to that function?

Comment: Yes, I got an error. Numpy works, and int works, but not torch tensors.

Comment: Then you won't be able to backpropagate through it.